# Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm receiving the above mentioned error after calling a hook mutation (toggleCartClose) from an onClick event, which needs to be actioned upon the onClick event (SickButton) being triggered. How do I resolve this?

Note: If I remove the `signIn();` call inside the onClick event, then the error goes away.

```
const signIn = props => {
  Router.push({
    pathname: '/signup',
    query: { fromCart: 'true' }
  })
};

const Cart = props => {

  const { data: dataQuery, error: errorQuery, loading: loadingQuery } = useQuery(
    LOCAL_STATE_QUERY,
  );

  const [ toggleCartClose ] = useMutation(
    TOGGLE_CART_CLOSE_MUTATION,
  );

  const [ toggleCart ] = useMutation(
    TOGGLE_CART_MUTATION,
  );

  return (
    <User>
      {({ data: { me }, loading, error }) => {
        ...
        return (
          <CartStyles open={dataQuery.cartOpen}>
            <header>
            ...
            <footer>
              <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan="2">
                  <div>
                    <SickButton loggedout disabled={loading} onClick={() => {alert('Please....'); signIn(); toggleCartClose()}} background={loading ? props => props.theme.grey : props => props.theme.blue}>Checkout</SickButton>
                  </div>                
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
          </footer>
          </CartStyles>
        );
      }}
    </User>
  )
};
```

Comment: As a first step, doing this is really bad practice: `onClick={() => {alert('Please....'); signIn(); toggleCartClose()}}` . Extract this into its own function within the component.  Might also try moving the signIn function inside the component function to see if the error goes away.  Looks like an issue with react trying to figure out the scope it should be using inline and getting it wrong

Comment: What is `Router` in this code?

Comment: @RyanCogswell It's referencing `Router from 'next/router';`

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this by moving the mutation hook call to the called route:

signup.js

```
  const [ toggleCartClose ] = useMutation(
    TOGGLE_CART_CLOSE_MUTATION,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fromCart) {
      toggleCartClose();
    }
  }, [urlReferer]);
```